# Software & Updates right setting in "other software" updates

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager, settings, 20.10

After upgrade to Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy I got some new package lines in this setting.

I like to know, which are important and should be marked for download.
Is my actual settings right ?

Thank you for help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing important on your list to select.

- The important sources are on the "Ubuntu Software" tab. Most folks want the "Updates" and "Security" boxes. The others are optional.
- "Source Code" is for folks who want to modify and recompile the software. If you don't know what that means, then you don't need to check any "Source Code" sources.

Comment: Thanks. I mean this section. Should I remove all this sources ?

Comment: Yes: "*There is nothing important on your list to select*"

Comment: Thanks much for help.